# Why does Mathematica crash at a certain recursion depth?

Tags: recursion

If I enter

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 70000}, x = x + 1]
```

I get

```
$RecursionLimit: Recursion depth of 70000 exceeded during evaluation of 1+x.
```

But at `$RecursionLimit = 80000`, Mathematica crashes (i.e. goes unresponsive for a little while and then clears all variables). Why is this? Is there some limiting factor that I can increase to go even further?

Comment: For me a more important question is why does this *still* crash the kernel? After 30 years, Wolfram still hasn't set up many of the basic catches that are required for a 'production system'.
For me the 'crash limit' is >80,000. And the time it spends in unresponsiveness is quite long compared to the time when $RecursionLimit = 70000. MMA 11 and MMA 12.

Comment: For me, it's much lower, around `$RecursionLimit = 16315` (varies).

Comment: It crashes because the subroutine stack gets exhausted.

Comment: I think that this depend on the amount of RAM of your system.

Comment: I think that you can gain some information on the crash following the Mathematica kernel in the Task Manager until it crash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is by no means unique to Mathematica. It crashes due to [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

Python, and many other interpreters, will also crash with [uncontrolled recursion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit). A major reason for `$RecursionLimit` (and Python's `setrecursionlimit`) is to avoid this.

---

> Is there some limiting factor that I can increase to go even further?

Some operating systems let you increase a process's stack size. Perhaps on Linux it's `ulimit -s`. I don't have a Linux box here to test.

Comment: `ulimit -s` will work for native code, but if the crash occurs in a part of the kernel which  uses java or similar managed runtime the stack size limit would have to be set via some other means.

Comment: @user130558 It does not use Java or "managed code"

Comment: `ulimit -s 65536` does prevent the crash with recursion limit of 70000 on Mathematica 12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit). With `ulimit -s 35000` or less (default being 8192 on Ubuntu) it crashes in `libWolframEngine.so` with a huge repeating backtrace, which is indeed a symptom of stack overflow due to recursion.